# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes when downloading torrent / watching youtube / using VLC

Tags: crash

So it's basically that. I am sure it froze at some other time as well, but 95% of the time, I am doing either of these three things, or worse, multiple. When downloading a torrent and using VLC at the same time for example, the whole computer will freeze totally. The mouse will hardly respond anymore, or not at all.

I have tried using different graphics drivers, to no avail. The fact that it will also freeze only when downloading torrents tells me that it probably doesn't have anything to do with it.

Using different torrent clients doesn't make a difference, transmission, deluge, qbittorrent, no difference.

I had the same problem on the last three versions of Ubuntu on this machine. I do not believe that the machine is running out of ram - I had purposely had htop open, and once it froze, there was still plenty.

I'd be grateful for any input on how to alleviate this problem.

Here's the inxi output:

```
  Host: desktop Kernel: 5.8.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 3.38.1 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B450 Pro4 serial: M80-CC008900074 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: P3.90 date: 12/12/2019 
Battery:
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 
  model: Logitech Marathon Mouse/Performance Plus M705 
  charge: 10% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics 
  bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 1 L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 28745 
  Speed: 2921 MHz min/max: 1400/3600 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
  1: 2818 2: 2952 3: 2954 4: 2954 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Picasso driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 0a:00.0 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.38.0 5.8.0-31-generic LLVM 11.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.1 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 0a:00.1 
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASRock driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 0a:00.6 
  Device-3: MCS Combo384 Amanero type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
  bus ID: 5-1:2 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-31-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: rtl8192ce v: kernel port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 04:d9:f5:c5:52:7b 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: ASRock driver: r8169 v: kernel port: c000 bus ID: 08:00.0 
  IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: a8:a1:59:11:b7:1c 
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:36:f5:26:8e 
  IF-ID-2: virbr0 state: down mac: 52:54:00:1c:cf:a2 
  IF-ID-3: virbr0-nic state: down mac: 52:54:00:1c:cf:a2 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 352.97 GiB (75.8%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: SA2000M8500G size: 465.76 GiB 
  Message: No Optical or Floppy data was found. 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.01 GiB used: 352.96 GiB (77.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
Swap:
  Alert: No Swap data was found. 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 47.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 47.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 306 Uptime: 4m Memory: 13.59 GiB used: 2.59 GiB (19.0%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 3342 
  Shell: Bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.1.07
```

edit:
swapon --show output

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   4G   0B   -2
```

grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: Do not think torrent is the problem, it just happens at same time.  A fast google search has quite a few hits with Linux freezing with your CPU.  Would check there first and see if anything comes close.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Kind of embarrassing that I hadn't had the idea to do it :) I found a tip to set the power supply idle control option from "Auto" to "typical current idle". Fingers crossed that that's the solution.

Comment: Your BIOS is outdated, and you have no swap. See http://www.asrock.com/support/index.asp?cat=BIOS

Comment: Ok, so power supply idle control had no effect, neither did a BIOS upgrade. I'm at a loss. It happens when doing different stuff, but the probability of a freeze is highest while torrenting, no doubt about it. I am probably going to buy a different motherboard and CPU..

Comment: Did you fix the swap problem? Edit your question and show me `swapon --show` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for checking back despite not being notified ;) I made a swapfile. Still no luck, system froze despite swap being available.

Comment: Ryzen's are notorious for RAM compatibility issues. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema had it run overnight, no errors.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /var/crash`. You may have a Ryzen CPU problem. Google for "ryzen recall linux", and here's one example... https://cobuildlab.com/blog/AMD-fixes-Ryzen-3000-problems-with-Linux/ and there are many more. Check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence. I have the same WiFi card and the same issue. I usually run Manjaro, but have been able to recreate the issue with an Ubuntu 21.04 live USB as well as the Manjaro 21.0.3 live USB. In both cases I had Deluge running with 20 torrents, VLC running a video on repeat and two YouTube videos also on. Using the WiFi card the machine would show the same symptoms as yours, and then reboot, consistently after about 2 hours.

It has also occured on my installed Manjaro partition too. When running only Deluge it would crash after maybe 4-5 hours, but with VLC running too it would happen quicker. I have also had it happen out of the blue at random times, but I THINK I had some YouTube video going or some network activity was occuring in each instance.

Today I tried this (deluge + vlc + youtube) using **wired network**, and so far it has been going steadily for 6 hours and counting. I will have this running the rest of today and tommorrow too to increase confidence that the WiFi card is the problem.

Have you tried running torrents and VLC on cabled network? Has it worked?

PS: I see I have hardware somewhat similiar to yours:

```
ystem:
  Kernel: 5.11.14-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11-x86_64 
  root=UUID=c398a086-6f8a-42e7-8d87-54c4578033a3 rw quiet apparmor=1 
  security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3 nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 
  dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Komplett product: Komplett PC v: N/A serial:  
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING v: Rev 1.xx serial:  
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4301 date: 03/04/2021 
Battery:
  Message: No system battery data found. Is one present? 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 15.07 GiB used: 3.25 GiB (21.6%) 
  Array-1: capacity: 128 GiB slots: 4 EC: None max-module-size: 32 GiB 
  note: est. 
  Device-1: DIMM_A1 size: No Module Installed 
  Device-2: DIMM_A2 size: 8 GiB speed: 3200 MT/s type: DDR4 
  detail: synchronous unbuffered (unregistered) bus-width: 64 bits 
  total: 64 bits manufacturer: Kingston part-no: KHX3200C18D4/8G 
  serial:  
  Device-3: DIMM_B1 size: No Module Installed 
  Device-4: DIMM_B2 size: 8 GiB speed: 3200 MT/s type: DDR4 
  detail: synchronous unbuffered (unregistered) bus-width: 64 bits 
  total: 64 bits manufacturer: Kingston part-no: KHX3200C18D4/8G 
  serial:  
CPU:
  Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G with Radeon Graphics socket: AM4 
  bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 2 family: 17 (23) model-id: 60 (96) 
  stepping: 1 microcode: 8600106 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 8 MiB 
  bogomips: 88668 
  Speed: 1397 MHz min/max: 1400/3700 MHz base/boost: 3700/4300 boost: enabled 
  volts: 1.2 V ext-clock: 100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1397 2: 1830 3: 1397 
  4: 1397 5: 1709 6: 1397 7: 1397 8: 1397 9: 2863 10: 1518 11: 1386 12: 1397 
  Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm adx aes aperfmperf apic arat avic avx avx2 bmi1 
  bmi2 bpext cat_l3 cdp_l3 clflush clflushopt clwb clzero cmov cmp_legacy 
  constant_tsc cpb cpuid cqm cqm_llc cqm_mbm_local cqm_mbm_total cqm_occup_llc 
  cr8_legacy cx16 cx8 de decodeassists extapic extd_apicid f16c flushbyasid 
  fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr fxsr_opt ht hw_pstate ibpb ibrs ibs irperf lahf_lm 
  lbrv lm mba mca mce misalignsse mmx mmxext monitor movbe msr mtrr mwaitx 
  nonstop_tsc nopl npt nrip_save nx osvw overflow_recov pae pat pausefilter 
  pclmulqdq pdpe1gb perfctr_core perfctr_llc perfctr_nb pfthreshold pge pni 
  popcnt pse pse36 rdpid rdpru rdrand rdseed rdt_a rdtscp rep_good sep sha_ni 
  skinit smap smca smep ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 stibp succor 
  svm svm_lock syscall tce topoext tsc tsc_scale umip v_vmsave_vmload vgif 
  vmcb_clean vme vmmcall wbnoinvd wdt xgetbv1 xsave xsavec xsaveerptr xsaveopt 
  xsaves 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
  Type: mds status: Not affected 
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full AMD retpoline, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, 
  STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds status: Not affected 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  bus-ID: 09:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:1636 class-ID: 0300 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati 
  unloaded: modesetting alternate: fbdev,vesa display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x285mm (20.0x11.2") 
  s-diag: 582mm (22.9") 
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-0 res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 94 
  size: 521x293mm (20.5x11.5") diag: 598mm (23.5") 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.40.0 5.11.14-1-MANJARO LLVM 11.1.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus-ID: 09:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1637 class-ID: 0403 
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus-ID: 09:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403 
  Device-3: Mackie Designs Onyx Blackjack type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
  bus-ID: 3-1:2 chip-ID: 0a73:0010 class-ID: 0102 
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.11.14-1-MANJARO running: yes 
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.17 running: no 
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes 
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.25 running: no 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: kernel 
  port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:1539 class-ID: 0200 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac:  
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: rtl8192ce v: kernel port: c000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8178 
  class-ID: 0280 
  IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac:  
  IP v4:  type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
  broadcast:  
  IP v6:  type: noprefixroute scope: link 
  WAN IP:  
Bluetooth:
  Message: No bluetooth data found. 
Logical:
  Message: No logical block device data found. 
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found. 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 5.44 TiB used: 118.8 GiB (2.1%) 
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Western Digital 
  model: WDS100T2B0C-00PXH0 size: 931.51 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B 
  logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 rotation: SSD serial:  
  rev: 211210WD temp: 27.9 C scheme: GPT 
  ID-2: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37960G 
  size: 894.25 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
  rotation: SSD serial:  rev: K1B3 scheme: MBR 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 type: USB vendor: Western Digital 
  model: WD Elements 25A3 size: 3.64 TiB block-size: physical: 4096 B 
  logical: 512 B serial:  rev: 1019 scheme: GPT 
  ID-4: /dev/sdc maj-min: 8:32 type: USB vendor: Verbatim model: STORE N GO 
  size: 14.75 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B serial:  
  rev: 1.00 scheme: MBR 
  Message: No optical or floppy data found. 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 734.07 GiB size: 721.48 GiB (98.28%) 
  used: 118.77 GiB (16.5%) fs: ext4 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
  maj-min: 259:5 label: N/A uuid: c398a086-6f8a-42e7-8d87-54c4578033a3 
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 260 MiB size: 256 MiB (98.46%) 
  used: 25.6 MiB (10.0%) fs: vfat block-size: 512 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
  maj-min: 259:1 label: SYSTEM uuid: 6E20-5105 
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found. 
Unmounted:
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1p2 maj-min: 259:2 size: 16 MiB fs: N/A label: N/A 
  uuid: N/A 
  ID-2: /dev/nvme0n1p3 maj-min: 259:3 size: 196.69 GiB fs: ntfs label: Windows 
  uuid: 5C0A20F70A20D036 
  ID-3: /dev/nvme0n1p4 maj-min: 259:4 size: 500 MiB fs: ntfs 
  label: Recovery tools uuid: 8018214D1821438E 
  ID-4: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1 size: 100 MiB fs: ntfs label: System Reserved 
  uuid: 083643023642EFEC 
  ID-5: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2 size: 98.46 GiB fs: ntfs label: N/A 
  uuid: 7CCC44A3CC445992 
  ID-6: /dev/sda3 maj-min: 8:3 size: 795.69 GiB fs: ext4 label: N/A 
  uuid: 43b36098-6834-4fc2-80c6-3ff8a4910117 
  ID-7: /dev/sdb1 maj-min: 8:17 size: 3.64 TiB fs: ext4 label: ElementsJohs 
  uuid: 35d2289c-e2aa-4951-a2a1-657936e58196 
  ID-8: /dev/sdc1 maj-min: 8:33 size: 14.75 GiB fs: ntfs label: N/A 
  uuid: 03C0A47A7F1FA59C 
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 10 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900 
  Device-1: 1-5:2 info: Primax USB Optical Mouse type: Mouse 
  driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 1.5 Mb/s 
  power: 100mA chip-ID: 0461:4d22 class-ID: 0301 
  Hub-2: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900 
  Device-1: 2-1:2 info: Western Digital Elements Desktop (WDBWLG) 
  type: Mass Storage driver: usb-storage interfaces: 1 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s 
  power: 8mA chip-ID: 1058:25a3 class-ID: 0806 serial:  
  Device-2: 2-3:3 info: Verbatim Flash Drive (StorenGo) type: Mass Storage 
  driver: usb-storage interfaces: 1 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s power: 304mA 
  chip-ID: 18a5:0243 class-ID: 0806 serial:  
  Hub-3: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900 
  Device-1: 3-1:2 info: Mackie Designs Onyx Blackjack type: Audio 
  driver: snd-usb-audio interfaces: 3 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 500mA 
  chip-ID: 0a73:0010 class-ID: 0102 
  Hub-4: 4-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-5: 5-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900 
  Device-1: 5-1:2 info: Logitech Illuminated Keyboard type: Keyboard,Mouse 
  driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  power: 300mA chip-ID: 046d:c318 class-ID: 0300 
  Hub-6: 6-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 28.2 C mobo: 0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 25.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 333 Uptime: 4h 05m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 247 
  tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: pacman: 1196 lib: 333 
  flatpak: 0 Shell: Bash (sudo) v: 5.1.0 running-in: xfce4-terminal 
  inxi: 3.3.04
```

Comment: Now that is really interesting! In the meantime I gave up and bought a new motherboard + an intel i3, as my suspicion was mostly that it had something to do with the CPU and MB. The freezes got much, much fewer. Now they happen every 3 weeks or so (maybe I am also using less torrent and vlc now, but it _definitely_ helped.). I still have the same wireless adapter. I will try to use wired for some time and post again in here!

Comment: I am pretty confindent it is a bug in the WiFi card. Take a look here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=260603

There are also other similar reports of this, for example:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1103468-start-0.html

The first link provides a way to solve this which you might want to try. For me I'm going to try a powerlink setup.

Comment: I have tried the modprobe command and I am currently torrenting and watching youtube without problems. I am also very sure by now that it is the Wifi card. Even if the modprobe commands don't help, switching the wifi card should certainly solve the problem, so I consider this topic answered. Thanks a ton for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for VLC. Navigate to:

```
Tools> Preferences> Video> Output> Automatic
```

Then change `Automatic` to `XVideo output (XCB)` or `X11 video output (XCB)`.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me, I think due to the **realtek** cards. Its possible cuz they have the least amount of combability with Linux as far as my experience goes with them, I hold a rtl8821ce which too doesn't have support and freezes casually, even when I am developing while listening to music. I hope they are able to fix the kernel, { Its a kernel leveled problem as far as my knowledge goes } it didn't happen on the 5.8 Generic Kernel with the rtl8821ce module dkms'ed into the system. But is happening non stop on the new 5.11 kernel which has the module inbuilt.

I hope ubuntu / kernel.org catches whats causing it and get ubuntu its stable name again

{ happens on 21.04 Ubuntu && 2021's release of pop_os }

Comment: Are there any external reference to this ? Any bug reports or discussion boards we should know about? Still thanks for pointing this out.